# SVN Remote Repository reachable from one machine but not from another

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008, svn

I have set up an SVN server on Windows 2008 R2 Server. I can browse the SVN Repositroy from my local machine, but my colleague can't from his machine ("can't connect to server" message).

However, both local machines are able to Telnet & http browse the remote server, and both firewalls are deactivated.

Comment: Are you serving your repositories through `svn://` or `http://`? If the latter, are you using Apache? Maybe IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the problematic workstation was behind a host building firewall and the port were blocked at that level. Sigh...

Answer (score 1):

Check the communication the other way around - try telnet from the SVN to the local machines.

Comment: I just noticed that the other machine is connected to internet via an entreprise router so it does not have a public IP. So I think I can't just telnet it that way I guess.